# Retrieving total RAM amount of a GCP instance

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I wonder if there is a way with Google SDK and the *gcloud* command on a linux shell to retrieve the total RAM amount of a GCP instance. I have already tried with *gcloud compute instances describe* but it doesn't seem to indicate what I am looking for.

Have you got any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get machine type of your instance this way

> gcloud compute instances list INSTANCE
> --format="value(machineType.scope(machineTypes))"

and describe its machine-type this way

> gcloud compute machine-types describe NAME

Therefore giving you RAM and some other characteristics.